# djNumberTextBox text-align:right

Tags: xpages

I want the content of Dojo component to be aligned right. Please find my Dojo Component code below.

```
<xe:djNumberTextBox id="djNumberTextBox1" style="text-align:right!important;">
</xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

My CSS Codes;

```
.dijitNumberTextBox input.dijitInputInner, .dijitCurrencyTextBox input.dijitInputInner, .dijitSpinner input.dijitInputInner
{
    padding-right: 1px;
    text-align: right;
}

.numeric input { text-align: right;}
```

[image: How It looks like (Screenshot)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for a specific number text box with a style "text-align:right":

```xml
<xe:djNumberTextBox 
    id="djNumberTextBox1"
    value="#{viewScope.number}" 
    style="text-align:right">
</xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

If you want to align all number text boxes to right then add to your CSS:

```css
.dijitNumberTextBox {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Please find the screenshot of my dojo field how it look like attached to top of my question. It does not work. The way i did is the only way i know. ( You also mentioned above with CSS or manually styled.)
Please find my whole page code in the next command.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
 <xe:djNumberTextBox id="djNumberTextBox1"
  value="#{viewScope.number}" style="text-align:right">
 </xe:djNumberTextBox>
</xp:view>

Comment: This does work for me. I tested on Domino 9.0.1, default theme and Crome 47 / Firefox 43

Comment: Thank you. There should be something else wrong in that NSF . I need to check it out. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Create a new database, add this little XPage and look if it works then.